Unexpected font change in alltt environment
I'm using the alltt environment so that I can have subscripts and superscripts with the typewrite font. However, for some reason, the font seems to be switching back to the typical italicized font unexpectedly. Included is a photo of both the code and representation in Overleaf. Namely, the s_1 parameter has a different font than that of s_2. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?


The \sb command requires math mode. Your code errors, which your editor is trying to tell you with Missing $ inserted

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. And please note that a screenshot is never compilable. So you should add code always as code block.

\sb is a math-mode command, so you would need to use $\sb{1}$ resp. \(\sb{1}\) inside alltt. But this also switches to math fonts for the subscript.
For text subscripts and superscripts LaTeX provides commands \textsubscript and \textsuperscript:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
ALG(G, s\textsubscript{1}, s\textsubscript{2});
    s1Dist = dijkstra(G, s\textsubscript{1})
    s2Dist = dijkstra(G, s\textsubscript{2})
\end{alltt}
\end{document}


Note: As told in a comment by @mbert, the whole s_2 in your example is in math mode, because of your mistake using \sb in text mode. To be able to continue TeX automatically switches to math mode at the first \sb. So the complete \sb{1}, s\sb{2}); is in math mode and uses math fonts. alltt switches back to text mode and typewriter font at the end of the line. In other cases such mistakes can result in quite long passages in math mode and additional error messages. So, as you see, you should always correct reported errors as soon as they happen and never ignore errors, just because TeX is still able to produce some kind of (often faulty) output.

Thank you very much! The (...) for math mode inside alltt is something I will be using often, I appreciate your help and response!

You get errors: don't underestimate them and always examine the first one that says
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.9 ALG(G, s\sb
               {1}, s\sb{2});

What does this mean? That \sb is a math mode command that TeX found while not in math mode.
Whatever output you get cannot to be trusted and you must fix the error. You could do
s\(\sb{1}\)

or
s\textsubscript{1}

The latter strategy will use monospaced text also for the subscript and seems better. You can avoid modifying the input by locally changing the meaning of \sb.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}

\AddToHook{env/alltt/begin}{\RenewCommandCopy{\sb}{\textsubscript}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
ALG(G, s\sb{1}, s\sb{2});
    s1Dist = dijkstra(G, s\sb{1})
    s2Dist = dijkstra(G, s\sb{2})
\end{alltt}

\end{document}


